# Php, $_POST method use like variable

Tags: php, post, mysqli, sql-insert

Can I do something like in PHP?:

```
for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    $anyway = $_POST['smth'].$i;
}
```

How do I use this in Mysql insert into function.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO try (column_1) VALUES ('".$anyway."')";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You're reassigning `$anyway` each time through the loop. At the end it will just be the value from the last iteration, so it's just `$anyway = $_POST['smth'] . "5";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend storing $_POST['smth'] in a variable before using it in your for loop.

```
$smth = $_POST['smth']; //remember to sanitize strings taken from user input
$anyway = ""; // Declare $anyway before the for loop to avoid overwriting it
for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    $anyway = $smth.$i;
}
```

Then you will need to set up and test your database connection:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Finally, prepare, bind, and execute your query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO (column_1) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $anyway);
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

Comment: The point of using a prepared statement is to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` rather than substituting variables into `$sql`.

Comment: You are correct; I've update my answer to include the bind_param() function as well as to declare the variable $anyway outside of the for loop to avoid overwriting it.